# How does 3D representation of linear congruential generator work?

Tags: random, 3d

I understand 3D hyperplanes can represent numbers generated by linear congruential generator. But I don't get how it determines the location for each number or point. Especially in a 3D cube? I mean, doesn't a point have to have X, Y, and Z values to be in there?! What if one of the numbers generated is "8"? It's just "8"... how would I know XYZ for that? (I hope you know what I'm talking about... couldn't post an image, sorry :/)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you generate batches of three pseudo-random numbers in a sequence from your linear congruential generator and use the first number in each batch as the x-dimension, the next as the y-dimension and the last as the z-dimension, you can then plot each batch of three pseudo-random numbers in a x-y-z cube. A similar argument goes for generating batches of *n* (*n* > 3) numbers, except you'll plot them in a hypercube.

Assume that you are generating each of those pseudo-random numbers with *b* bits. There are then 2<sup>nb</sup> possible numbers that would have to be generated to fill the (hyper)cube (which will be a very large number, for any typical value of *b*). However, if the generator has a period of less than 2<sup>nb</sup> (which will almost always be the case for practical purposes), it won't fill all the available spaces in the cube (or hypercube, if *n* > 3). It will only fill some of the spaces.

What's more, the filled spaces may be located in planes (or hyperplanes, if *n* > 3) passing through the (hyper)cube, with spaces in-between the (hyper)planes that represent numbers that the generator will never produce because it repeats its cycle without ever producing such a number. This occurs because the pseudo-random numbers are serially correlated. You can see this behaviour at any dimensionality but the number of (hyper)planes on which the pseudo-random numbers are located reduces as the dimensionality *n* increases, so the behaviour becomes much more obvious as *n* gets larger.

This can be a particular problem in when using the generated pseudo-random numbers as input to a simulation because the simulation can then produce output that is more an artefact of the imperfections of the pseudo-random numbers than a consequence of the simulated model.

The Wikipedia article on [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is excellent.

(EDITED TO ADD AN EXAMPLE)

Here is a linear congruential generator (with very poor parameters selected deliberately) implemented in Python. Pseudo-random numbers with an even index are assigned to x values and those with odd numbers are assigned to y values.

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def lcg (X, a, c, m):
    return (a * X + c) % m;

x = []
y = []
X = 0
for i in range(1000):
    X = lcg(X,43,5,256)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        x.append(X)
    else:
        y.append(X)

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

This script produces the following output:

[image: LCG output with bad parameters]

You can see that the resulting (x,y) pairs are all found on a small number of straight lines and pairs that appear in-between the lines can never be produced by the generator. The same thing can be done in three or more dimensions to see how generators with better parameters than I've used here still produce outputs that sit on lines, planes or hyperplanes in 2, 3, or *n*-dimensional space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! :) Would you please also explain if n>3, how numbers are plotted in a hypercube?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Glad to help. If the answer is useful to you, please upvote it (click on the upper triangle). If it resolves your problem, please check (tick) it to say that you've accepted the answer. That way other people won't spend time answering a question that has already been satisfactorily answered.

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized it was your reply!!! I thought it was the site's auto-something haha :P I tried upvoting you, but the site doesn't let me because I have too few points I guess?

Comment: Perhaps. You should at least be able to accept the answer -- indeed, accepting an answer adds to your reputation score.

Comment: Ok! So should/may I ask how xyz (or more) are determined if n>3 in a new question?

Comment: Thank you for the additional information! The chart is very helpful.
What happens when using just numbers, but not a generator?

Comment: Sorry I was editing the above comment but it expired :/ so I'm rewriting it below.

Comment: How do you make a chart when using just numbers, but not a generator?
If you have a bunch of numbers you would like to test randomness for, which (mostly) don't (seem to) have any indices..., I mean, if it's an 8, for example, it would be 2x2x2 so the index is 3, an odd number, but for most of numbers, there are no indices - for instance for numbers like 11 or 13. Sorry if I'm confusing as hell >_< & I apologize I keep hitting 'Enter' by mistake thinking it just makes a new line of text but actually it publishes the comment lol

Comment: If you want to test the quality of an LCG, the [spectral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_test) is the most stringent test that you could apply.

Comment: With respect to your point about the indices, I don't think I really understand you. I just used the index `i` in my example to split the stream of pseudo-random numbers into two groups - the even-indexed ones I made the `x` values and the odd-indexed ones I made the `y` values. I could equally have taken the first 500 numbers in the sequence and called them `x` values and the second 500 numbers in the sequence and called them `y` values. You would still have seen lines of points on the graph - they would just have been different lines.

Comment: @Stano: I think you'll find that the problem you're having is that, as the Wikipedia article says "A further problem of LCGs is that the lower-order bits of the generated sequence have a far shorter period than the sequence as a whole if m is set to a power of 2". By using the modulus of the x and y values to plot the results, you're using those lower-order bits. If you divide the x and y values by some number to get the values to plot, you'll use the higher-order bits and I expect they will be much less of an obvious pattern.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Simon, you're right that using modulo was not good idea to transform 30bit random numbers to interval 0-512. Finally changed it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/7VmR9/14/ Best regards

Comment: Ah thank you, that is very clear! And the spectral test link is great :) Do you know of software that can perform the test on just numbers / data alone not requiring hooking up to a number generator? I am assuming we can't do it with chart functions of Excel or Google Spreadsheet...?

Comment: I don't know of any software that would perform the test on just a stream of numbers, however, if you have the source code, it would be easy to replace the call to the LCG to a call to a function that returns the next value in a stream of numbers stored in a text file, for instance.

Comment: Thank you again :) After a little bit of research, I found things called '3D scatter plots.' It looks like this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Scatter_plot.jpg
Do you think with it I can try to find patterns of data points in a cube like in Spectral Test, with just a stream of numbers?

Comment: You could use scatter plots but a) you would not have a quantitative measure of how good the LCG is and b) it would not help you much with a relatively good LCG where the points appear on hyperplanes, whereas the spectral test would give you both a quantitative measure of how good any LCG is, and it would handle high-dimensionality cases.